# Why my Button in worldspace canvas can't be pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas

For my 2D mobile game, I have a button in a worldspace canvas but when I pressed it nothing append.

On most forum they say to set the canvas Event Camera to Main Camera and unchecked ignore Reversed Graphic in graphic ray caster to resolve the problem.

I did it but the problem is still here.

Also, I have others canvas in my scene, one canvas in overlay and 37 in different GameObjects (one in each box of the racetrack you can see in the "in game" picture), I don't know if it could interfere.

Do you have ideas to fix it?

Here's a picture of my game scene:

2D

[image]

3D

[image]

In Game:(ps: this is normal that there is only the button that is active on the canvas)

[image]

Canvas settings:

[image]

Button GO settings:

[image]

Hierarchy:

[image]

EventSystem:

[image]

Tell me if you need more information!

Comment: Do you have an eventsystem in your  hierarchy

Comment: @BugFinder I add the hierarchy and the EventSystem in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check true the Raycast target on Image component in button. because i see it is false in your pictures.
In addition, make sure your button image not to be covered by other UI Image.

Comment: Thanks @FuatSeref , I unchecked it because on another forum they said that unchecked Raycast Target could work but it doesn't, I forgot to check it again, my bad.